# Keep alignments in Named Entity Recognition tasks after cleaning text

Tags: nlp, text-mining, data-cleaning, named-entity-recognition, brat

I am working on a Named Entity Recognition (NER) task and the entities are annotated in BRAT format (.txt + .ann). I have implemented some regular expressions to clean the texts before using my model, but if I modify the text I have to align the entities' offsets of the annotations. This task is relatively straightforward and after this, I can use my NLP model to classify the different entity classes. However, once I get the classification of the model I need to re-align the recognized entities in the original text, i.e. change the offsets of the cleaned text to those I had before the use of regular expressions. Is there a way to keep track of the original offsets after cleaning texts?

Comment: Can you post an example of the data, both before and after preprocessing? It'd also help if you could edit in the code you use for preprocessing. It's impossible to know how much adjustment should be being applied without any information regarding the data or code.

Comment: Example:
I have the sentence "This's the model" and the annotation of the word "model" with offsets 11-15. As a preprocessing, I have the following simple regular expressions that replace ['s] to [is] and [this] to [it], thus the sentence is "It is the model". Now, the word "model" is in the 10-14 offsets.
If the NLP system classifies the word "the", which is in positions 6-8 in the cleaned text, how can I recover the positions in the original text (that is 7-9)?

Comment: This sounds like you can do that with simple calculations. Subtract the length of the string you're removing, and add the length of the string you're replacing the removed string with.